# asterisk meetme conference - record only when there are 2 or more participants

Tags: asterisk

I have an operator  connect to a Meetme conference room and use a web script to make out going call that are being connected to the same room (1 outgoing call at a time with 1 operator in the room).

The trouble im having is that asterisk is recoring conference room. Is there any way to record only outgoing connected calls?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can record only outgoing lines using mixmonitor app. However in all lines will be same sound ffrom conference.